# Add large sharepoint list to sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, splistitem, list-template, large-lists

I have SharePoint list with big number of items (13879 items).

I saved it with content, download list template and change GUID in manifest.xml file.

after I add it to .cab and renamed to .stp file and upload this list template to SharePoint site.

Now I am trying to add it on SharePoint but it doesn't loads all items,  it loads items only from 8000 to 11000. For this example 9217 items.

[image]

if I am doing same at this list template saving with no content, it adds list to SharePoint and everything is Okay, but not works for big number of items

also when I am trying to open this list with 9217 items, The page you're looking for doesn't exist. is displayed.

list view threshold is increased from 5000 to 15000.
[image]

so how can I add this large list?

Comment: How large is the template file (stp) before editing it?

Comment: Do you have site collection administrator permission while doing these operations? If yes, you may have to increase the "list view threshold" from 5000 to 15000 while doing the operation.

Comment: .stp file is 1969 kb

Comment: and list view threshold is increased from 5000 to 15000 already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is limit for the template.
You can change the value with PowerShell on SharePoint 2013:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration")    
$webservice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService   
#Get the current Maximum Size
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize

#Set New Limit and update
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = 524288000 #500 MB
$webservice.Update()
```

or try create Template from PowerShell, it looks like Time-Out from UI: [How to create Template from PowerShell Here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ce7cb6ff-03f0-403b-93ef-c272984264ed/time-out-error-when-saving-a-list-as-a-template?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Just copy and paste this code to PowerShell?

Comment: yes, it should work this way

Comment: what permissions will I need for this code?

Comment: Farm Administrator, run PowerShell as Admin

Comment: but my .stp file is 2mb will help increasing upload limit of template?

Comment: ok, so probably the UI timed out, you can try to create list from template via PowerShell, here is example: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ce7cb6ff-03f0-403b-93ef-c272984264ed/time-out-error-when-saving-a-list-as-a-template?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: yes, one of the reason was UI time out and I create list with .STP file template using PowerShell so thank you @Zdeněk Vinduška

Comment: Great, I edited the answer, can you mark it as correct? Thank You.

Comment: okay I will mark it

Answer (score 0):

@Vaso There is a threshold limit of 5000 items in a list by default unless you have permissions to change the setting. However, a work around is setup view and sort the views by meta Data.

Good Meta Data Articles: [MetaData](https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-edit-document-metadata-sharepoint/), [Lots of Articles](https://sharepointmaven.com/?s=Meta%20Data&post_type=post)

Comment: list view threshold is increased from 5000 to 15000 already